# Husserlian Critiques of Scheler

Tags: phenomenology, husserl

It’s known that although Max Scheler’s phenomenology was heavily inspired by Husserl, he was no student of Husserl. So, the two had disagreements on how to do phenomenology. While I’m acutely aware of how Scheler criticized Husserl, the reverse is what I’m wanting to know.

What are some of Husserl’s most potent objections to Scheler’s phenomenology as a whole? Answers can include critiques by later Husserlians.

To give some context: Scheler liked Husserl's expansive approach to intuition, but disagreed fundamentally regarding our awareness of values. Contra Husserl, Scheler held that value-awareness founded perceptual awareness (that is, *feelings* provide the basic orientation to being able to perceive any object *as an object*; whereas Husserl held that feelings needed objectivating content from perception). Much of Scheler's critiques of Husserl come from this basis: Scheler substituted the *transcendental ego* with the *person*, Scheler spoke of a phenomenological *attitude*, not a *method*.

Husserl would have accused Scheler of making an error similar to what he thought Heidegger did: transforming phenomenology into a mere philosophical anthropology. I'm looking for something deeper or more substantial along these lines, or, another line of attack Husserl (or later Husserlians) made.

Comment: Excellent question! I doubt that there are many people here who know Scheler but I'd love to see this one answered. In some weeks time, I may even find.the time to.do.some research and answer it myself hehe

Comment: Apparently Husserl could've countered back or outright rejected those criticisms from Scheler such as Husserl's detached bracketing lacking Scheler's emphasis on value and emotions, maybe you could've added the most heavy blow(s) of Scheler's criticism towards Husserl from your said acute awareness?

Comment: @DoubleKnot Added some further context, including the main line of attack Scheler used against Husserl. There's others he used, but imo, they all rest on what I added above.

Comment: Husserl used to criticize J S Mill's logic as impure psychologism, same perhaps would be applicable to criticize Scheler's value/emotion-laden phenomenology inherently mixed with passivity or privation, which perhaps is hard to attain Husserl's transcendental and later eidetic reduction phases. Kant perhaps would agree with Husserl on this. A deeper reason may be connected to the later private language argument since the private language needed to convey unbracketed personal value as reflected in its corresponding passive mental state is impossible without outside access and rule check...